# About the internal logic of "Memory Cannot be read" error in windows

Tags: windows, memory-management

We occasionally come into this error when running a EXE on windows.

How does OS know if a specific memory can be read or not?

Comment: Could be any of a number of reasons, but one is if the address being read isn't backed by RAM - a hole in the address map.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by `a hole in the address map`?

Comment: @wamp: Not all of a process's address space references readable and writable memory. Some of it is used to communicate with hardware - to read and write data to and from the serial port, for instance, you might read and write bytes at address 0x40000000. When you blend memory and devices into a flat address space like that, sometimes you create pockets of space that don't correspond to anything readable. And some addresses just make no sense to  read from.

Comment: Or you might just be reading memory you don't have access/permission to. That's actually more likely. The processor (actually, the memory management unit) keeps track of logical to physical addresses, and knows when you've made a request it can't fulfill. See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) for more information.

Comment: In my case it's caused by broken Import Table, which of the cases does it fit in?

Comment: @wamp: You'll have to provide a lot more detail/code to answer that. Also note, I won't be notified of any replies you make here unless you prefix my name with a `@` character (as I've done with your name).

Answer (score 0):

The CPU walks the [page table entries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) pointed to via the CR3 register - if a matching, valid PTE is not found, this hardware exception will be raised and the NT kernel will turn it into a SEH exception.